# How to sort compound index in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following entries in mongo db:

```
{ "_id" : { "t" : 1491329960, "id" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : { "t" : 1491329961, "id" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : { "t" : 1491329961, "id" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "t" : 1491329961, "id" : 3 } }
```

I need to find largest `t` for specific `id`

(assume `test` is collection and database names and specific `id = 2`)

---

In mongo client I need to run:

```
db.test.find( { '_id.id' : 2 } ).sort( { '_id.t' : -1} ).limit( 1 )
```

---

However, in `pymongo`, below doesn't work

```
from pymongo import MongoClient as mc
mc()['test']['test'].find( { '_id.id' : 2 } ).sort( { '_id.t' }, -1 )[0]
```

and raises:

```
TypeError: first item in each key pair must be a string
```

What should I do to get what I want using `pymongo`? Obviously, I can get everything and sort in python later, but that's wrong performance-wise

Comment: `mc()['test']['test'].find( { '_id.id' : 2 }, sort = [ ( '_id.t',  -1 )] )[0]`
or
`mc()['test']['test'].find_one( { '_id.id' : 2 }, sort = [ ( '_id.t',  -1 )] )`
seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python syntax is a little different than Javascript:

```
find( { '_id.id' : 2 } ).sort([('_id.t', -1)])[0]
```

"sort" takes a list of pairs of (fieldname, direction).